# Get images from webkit cache with a script

Tags: php, caching, webkit, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the great **wkhtmltopdf** tool to transform web-pages to PDF files with **PHP**.

There are several pictures on the pages and I would like to save them separately. Using **CURL** or **file_get_contents()** is not an option, because this would lead to too many single requests.

Since wkhtmltopdf has this "--cache-dir" option, I thought I just could get the files from the webkit cache. But unfortunately this is not as trivial as I thought.
Caching the images works. But they are not human readable. They are stored in directories from 0-9 and a-f in **.d** files.

Is there any chance to write a small shell script or something like that which I can exec() within PHP to get those images out of the **.d** files?

Perhaps someone can give me a hint, at the moment I just don't know what I can search for.

greets,
Alex